Ad-hoc-chess-font related log-warnings: Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
This is a follow up of my question about using a specific set of pieces, berlin, for typing chess moves and diagrams. Yes, this works and i am very thankful for this!
A small drawback is in the latex-log, where there are a lot of messages like
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!

repeated in larger blocks in consecutive lines.
Here is a relatively minimal sample to reproduce the warnings:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xskak}
\setchessfontfamily{berlin}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
{\centering
\newchessgame[setfen=2b1k2r/2qnbppp/p2pp3/6P1/1r1NPP1P/2N2Q1B/1PP5/2KR3R b k - 1 16
, moveid=16b]
\chessboard[margintop=false, showmover, moverstyle=triangle]
\par}
\end{document}

It produces the excellent diagram:

however in the log of pdflatex the final lines are:
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chessfss/enpassant/lsbberlin.fd)
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font chess-berlin-lsb!
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{/usr/share/texmf-dist/fon
ts/enc/chess/enpassant/chess-berlin-board.enc}] (./test_font.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 )</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/chess/enpassant/chess-berlin-board-fig-raw
.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss10.pfb>
Output written on test_font.pdf (1 page, 25607 bytes).

If lualatex is used instead to compile the tex document, then the repeated warning is:
Missing character: There is no 0 (U+0030) in font chess-berlin-lsb!

I tried to use an own 0 in lines like:
\newcommand{\nulchar}{\textvisiblespace}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\nulchar}{T1}{`0}

(in T1 and in the LSB? and LSBC? possible encodings), but the problem remains. Please help, the log-information is useful in connection with \typeout messages for blocks that still need edits or fixes. A solution is highly appreciated!

for some reason the font has no white square declared, but I don't know if it a bug or if there was a reason. Use \makeatletter \DeclareTextCommand\cfss@WhiteEmptySquare  {LSB}{{\cfss@whitefieldcolor\cfss@whitepiececolor \phantom{Z}}} \makeatother.

@UlrikeFischer Thank You so much! This solves my problem, the log is quick and clean. Please convert the comment to an answer, I'd be glad to upvote+accept!

for some reason the font has no white square declared, but I don't know if it a bug or if there was a reason (that is all long time ago).
You can try
\makeatletter 
 \DeclareTextCommand\cfss@WhiteEmptySquare  {LSB} {{\cfss@whitefieldcolor\cfss@whitepiececolor \phantom{Z}}} 
\makeatother

(but I'm not sure what will happens with the colors ...)
